# How do I remove the seperation between folder and file grouping in GUI sorts

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

Is there a way to make windows treat files and folders the same for the sorts options? If I try to sort by newest in Explorer it's always files at the top, and then after all the files it shows me folders. Currently sorting by descending date modified I have a file that was modified in 2012 followed by a folder modified in 2023. Is mixing them possible?

Edit: I have this issue on my linux machines as well so I understand if it's just how file explorers are designed.

Comment: I don't believe you can change that behavior without some third-party product. As you say, i've seen many different file managers handle this problem differently, but I don't recall having ever seen one that offered a means to customize the default behavior.